# linq to sql search not working for unicode characters

Tags: vb.net, linq, unicode

I am using LINQ to SQL for firebird database. Its working fine in all aspects. But issue when i try to search data via search value in object it doesn't work. 
I tried below code

```
Dim result = (From c In db.mytable Where c.data.Contains("Є start").ToList
```

It returns result but if tried same in this way

```
Dim searchval = "Є start"
Dim result = (From c In db.mytable Where c.data.Contains(searchval).ToList
```

It return no result. What am i doing wrong. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebird Database does not recognize unicode/cyrillic letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785736/firebird-database-does-not-recognize-unicode-cyrillic-letters)

Comment: If you googled "firebird database unicode" you would have found a lot of relevant hits. In addition to the above, there's this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012300/how-can-i-upgrade-firebird-for-the-unicode-data